# Not able to access Hive Tables through JDBC in Hortonworks Sandbox 2.0

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using Hortonworks Sandbox 2.0. I tried the following program in the Eclipse IDE, but was not table to access my Hive tables. Got the following errors. What do I have to do to resolve this?

I used this also: `hive –service hiveserver`, and got *Not able to connect*. I am using VMware.

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;

    public class HiveJdbcClient {
    private static String driverName = “org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver”;

    /**
    * @param args
    * @throws SQLException
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
    Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(“jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default”, “”, “”);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = “testHiveDriverTable”;
    stmt.executeQuery(“drop table ” + tableName);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(“create table ” + tableName + ” (key int, value string)”);
    // show tables
    String sql = “show tables ‘” + tableName + “‘”;
    System.out.println(“Running: ” + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
    System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
    // describe table
    sql = “describe ” + tableName;
    System.out.println(“Running: ” + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
    System.out.println(res.getString(1) + “\t” + res.getString(2));
    }

    // load data into table
    // NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
    // NOTE: /tmp/a.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
    String filepath = “/tmp/a.txt”;
    sql = “load data local inpath ‘” + filepath + “‘ into table ” + tableName;
    System.out.println(“Running: ” + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    // select * query
    sql = “select * from ” + tableName;
    System.out.println(“Running: ” + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + “\t” + res.getString(2));
    }

    // regular hive query
    sql = “select count(1) from ” + tableName;
    System.out.println(“Running: ” + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
    System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
    }
    }
```

—-
    GOT ERROR

```
Exception in thread “main” java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to 172.31.153.71:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:106)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at com.coe.convert.hive.temp.htw.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:28)
```

Comment: Are you running this program within the Sandbox or on your host machine? If running on your host machine you need to use the Sandbox IP address

Comment: 1) i work from from my eclipse it not working . 2)also i run as a jar in vmware sandbox - there also not get the connection. its got hang ... not able to get the system. i gave the ip which is mentioned in the etc/hosts file. how to connect from inside the sadbox and outside.3) facing lot of issues while connecting using vmware (vsphere server) loading hortonwork imgae. need suggestions.

Comment: i mentioned my vsphere client addess

Answer (score 0):

Run hive on another port. And then use the new port number it will work. Use the following command to change the port number 10000 to 10001.

`hive --service hiveserver -p 10001`

Then Use ,

```
172.31.153.71:10000/default
```